# inject event to service

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

Is there a way to inject an event in a service in order to make the service kind of event agnostic?
In prose:
The service says: Hey, give me any Event and i will instanciate it and fire it after i have done my work.

I guess its difficult because the Events can be structured very different:
Event1 expects three parameters in the constructor and Event2 only one.

The purpose would be to reduce dependencies in a bundle and at the same time give it flexibilty for fe custom loggers to hook into the service.

How can i achieve something like this?

Maybe the other way around: fire an event of the service and make the listener event agnostic?

Comment: Do you want to fire only custom events or also events provided by Symfony2 or another bundle?

Comment: i would like to keep it as flexible as possible, so i guess any event

Comment: How do you want to retrieve the event? Does the service retrieve just the name of the event? Do you already have any idea how the (possible) arguments of the event are given to your service?

Comment: right now i would say this is somehow not working, maybe it doesnt even make sense, because actually only the bundle itself can know what would be suitable to put into an event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the caller of the service does know about the arguments of the Event and the listener of the event does know about the event it would be possible to create the event.

I base my example on the example in the Symfony2 cook book: [How to extend a Class without using Inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/class_extension.html).

Normally you would dispatch an event like this:

```
$event = new HandleUndefinedMethodEvent($this, $method, $arguments);
$this->dispatcher->dispatch('foo.method_is_not_found', $event);
```

In your service you could add a method to create new events:

```
public function createEvent($name, $class, $arguments)
{
    ...
    $eventClass = new \ReflectionClass($class);
    $event = $eventClass->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
    $this->dispatcher->dispatch($name, $event);
}
```

In this case the service does not need to know about the event, however, as mentioned above both invoker and the listener does have to know about.

Comment: yes thats a good idea, but here the arguments come from outside the service, which is not really useful. i really doubt my approach, meanwhile.

Comment: If you want to have some logic in your controller to control the arguments given to the event I would implement multiple helper services. Depending on the type of event I would call this helper service which calculates the parameters for the event and then return to your main service to dispatch the event.